# Local DNS server convert to Public

Tags: dns

I made a local DNS-server
pc.home.local   192.168.1.254

how could I switch this local domain into a public one for free
that I can type pc.home.local and enter my website from anywhere

Comment: You cannot.  Your question is unclear.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: first off, you cannot use .local. it is only for inside your LAN. Second, DNS registrations are not free. you will have to pay at least a little money per year to have a domain name. third if you are on a residential network, you must make sure you have a dedicated public IP (not CGNAT) and that your domain registrar supports DDNS registrations. fourth you will need a piece of software deployed on your network to detect changes to your public IP, and update the registrar. choose your registrar based on what providers your software supports. finally there is all the NAT/Firewall work....

Comment: @FrankThomas .tk registrations are free. AFAIK they always have been.

Comment: @davidgo fair enough. I recall IANA recommending that all tld's charge  a reasonable but non-zero amount as a fraud deterrent, but that recollection is from the long long ago (late 90's) so neither my memory nor the influence of IANA are likely too have stood the test of time. My point remains largely unchanged, but I;ll defer to your wisdom on particular tld cost.

Answer (score 1):

**What you *can* do for free:**

1. Check what's your router's public IP address (the IP address of the
   router's internet/WAN port).
2. Configure it for port forwarding so that incoming traffic on
   applicable TCP ports is routed to your web server. For example, HTTP
   traffic runs on port 80, and HTTPS traffic on port 443. Instructions are
   in the documentation, from your ISP, or by searching the internet.

Once you get that done, you can access your web server over the internet by pointing your browser to `https://your-public-ip/`.

I know of 2 free DNS name registrars; [Freenom](https://www.freenom.com/) and [Dot.tk](http://www.dot.tk/). With them, you can register a domain name for free. The free top-level domains available are .TK, .ML, .GA, .CF and .GQ., so you could have something like `oandygames.tk`, if that's available.

Unfortunately at this moment (Feb 11 2023) it appears their domain registration isn't working.

**What you can *not* do for free, but can pay for:**

You can't have domain name xxx.yyy.local, as ".local" isn't an allowed top-level domain name. Wikipedia has an up-to-date list of possible [top-level domain names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains). These domains are not free, but they aren't too expensive either. For example, Domain.com (sorry but can't link here) prices start from $1.99. Please note that domain registrations aren't forever, with both free and paid registrars you will need to renew your registration periodically.

This will add your domain name linked to your router's public IP address to the public domain name registry. When done you can browse to `mydomainname` just like any website.

Please note Frank Thomas's and davidgo's feedback. Their points about DMZ, firewalls, static IP, and NAT are *extremely* important.

I'd suggest talking to your ISP. For example, they may have policies that prevent domain name registration on the public IPs of their clients or your public IP address gets randomly changed which means you will need to update the DNS records or something.

Comment: so i cannot do oandygames.game or oandygames.com for free on my dns server to be publicly resolved

Comment: @oandygames - No, otherwise why would the rest of use pay for Domain Names ?

Answer (score 0):

You cant practically do exactly what you have asked - specifically pc.home.local can only be resolved on your - the ".local" is not resolvable outside the LAN.

You thus have 3 problems to overcome -

1. Your LAN is behind NAT, meaning it cant be directly reached using standard IPv4 from the wider Internet.  **Assuming your router is not behind Carrier Grade NAT** you can configure your router to forward ports of interest to 192.168.1.254.  You could even set it up as a DMZ.  **This has significant security implications by exposing your device directly to the Internet**.
2. If your routers IP address is static you can use this in DNS.  If not you would need to work out a dynamic DNS solution which may cost $.  Alternatively you could bypass the whole issue with a VPN with a static (which would fix cgn ad well), but again $$$.  You could possibly do it for free for a limited time using a free VOS from Amazon or Linode, but this is technically challenging and you will need to pay in the future.
3. The other responses **are not entirely correct** about having to pay for a domain name.  You can register a domain ending in ".tk" for free - http://www.dot.tk/en/index.html?lang=en - you would then set up an A record pointing to your external IPv4 address.  You would use the .tk domain in place of the .local one.

There may be more complex hacks you can do to keep pc.home.local but they are complex and fragile. Im thinking along the lines of setting up pc.home.local.YOURDOMAIN.tc and then using YOURDOMAIN.tc as a search domain for relative addresses.

Comment: dot.tk was one of the free registrars I mentioned. As I said, I didn't link them simply because their website wouldn't open. I noticed later that both that and freenom.com actually did eventually open, I just took a helluva long time :-)

Comment: ... omigod they _are_ gadawful slow to open... Interestingly it appears they're either the same company  or at least connected, as at least the KB and whois on dot.tk site lead to freenom.com services :-)

Comment: And they seem to be having some issues. my.freenom.com (sign-in, KB) is down, registration appears to be offline on both sites.